# como puedo solucionar esto

Tags: mysql-workbench

*Buenos dias, soy nuevo en esto y estoy intentando crear una base datos pero me da errores que no se como solucionarlos aqui les dejo el scrips,la verda estoy un poco perdido en esto la verdad le agradeceria mucho que me pudieran colaborar con esto casi es de vida o muerte, el principal problema lo tengo con las llaves foraneas*
`` FOREIGN KEY (`clases_idclase' at line 11 SQL Code: ``

````
 ```CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datos`.`merma_exceso` (
      `idmerma_exceso` INT NOT NULL,
      `tipo_entrada` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
      `cantiadad` FLOAT NOT NULL,
      `valor` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
      `clases_idclases` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idmerma_exceso`),
      INDEX `fk_merma_exceso_clases1_idx` (`clases_idclases` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_merma_exceso_clases1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`clases_idclases`)
        REFERENCES `datos`.`clases` (`idclases`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE)
    ENGINE = InnoDB```
````

*SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed*

*Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch*

Comment: Tres cosas para que entiendas la clave de este error: 1. Cuando defines llaves foráneas, la tabla que indicas en `REFERENCES` **debe existir ya**, así, si estás ejecutando varios `CREATE TABLE` debes poner los de esas tablas primero. 2. Las columnas **deben tener la misma definición en ambas tablas**, mismo tipo, mismo tamaño, mismas restricciones... 3. La columna de la tabla referida debe ser **llave primaria** o ser **única** en dicha tabla. Revisa eso y nos dices. Si no lo puedes resolver, muéstranos el `CREATE TABLE` de la tabla `clases`.

Answer (score 0):

Tres cosas para que entiendas la clave de este error:

#### 1. Verificar el orden en `CREATE TABLE` sucesivos

Cuando defines llaves foráneas, la tabla que indicas en `REFERENCES` **debe existir ya**, así, si estás ejecutando varios `CREATE TABLE` debes poner los de esas tablas primero.

Así, el siguiente código fallará, porque la tabla `clases` se crearía luego, cuando se intenta la referencia en el primer `CREATE` la misma **no existe aún**:

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datos`.`merma_exceso` (
      `idmerma_exceso` INT NOT NULL,
      `tipo_entrada` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
      `cantiadad` FLOAT NOT NULL,
      `valor` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
      `clases_idclases` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idmerma_exceso`),
      INDEX `fk_merma_exceso_clases1_idx` (`clases_idclases` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_merma_exceso_clases1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`clases_idclases`)
        REFERENCES `datos`.`clases` (`idclases`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datos`.`clases` (
      `idclases ` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
      -- otras columnas 
    )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Para que funcione,  debes invertir el orden de los `CREATE TABLE` de modo **que la tabla exista cuando se intente referir a ella**. Esto debe ser así, siempre que haya tablas a las que se haga referencia, se debe crear esas tablas **primero**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datos`.`clases` (
      `idclases ` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
      -- otras columnas 
    )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datos`.`merma_exceso` (
      `idmerma_exceso` INT NOT NULL,
      `tipo_entrada` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
      `cantiadad` FLOAT NOT NULL,
      `valor` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
      `clases_idclases` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idmerma_exceso`),
      INDEX `fk_merma_exceso_clases1_idx` (`clases_idclases` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_merma_exceso_clases1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`clases_idclases`)
        REFERENCES `datos`.`clases` (`idclases`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

#### 2. Verificar que las columnas sean exactamente iguales

Las columnas **deben tener la misma definición en ambas tablas**, mismo tipo, mismo tamaño, mismas restricciones...

Esto fallará por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datos`.`clases` (
      `idclases ` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
      -- otras columnas 
    )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datos`.`merma_exceso` (
      `idmerma_exceso` INT NOT NULL,
      `tipo_entrada` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
      `cantiadad` FLOAT NOT NULL,
      `valor` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
      `clases_idclases` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idmerma_exceso`),
      INDEX `fk_merma_exceso_clases1_idx` (`clases_idclases` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_merma_exceso_clases1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`clases_idclases`)
        REFERENCES `datos`.`clases` (`idclases`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Porque la columna de `clases` que declaras como relacionada con `clases_idclases` en `merma_exceso` es de tipo `VARCHAR(250)`, mientras que `clases_idclases` es del tipo `INT`.

#### 3. Se debe garantizar la unicidad en la tabla referida

La columna de la tabla referida debe ser **llave primaria** o ser **única** en dicha tabla.

Esto fallará:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datos`.`clases` (
      `idclases` INT NOT NULL
      -- otras columnas 
    )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datos`.`merma_exceso` (
      `idmerma_exceso` INT NOT NULL,
      `tipo_entrada` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
      `cantiadad` FLOAT NOT NULL,
      `valor` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
      `clases_idclases` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idmerma_exceso`),
      INDEX `fk_merma_exceso_clases1_idx` (`clases_idclases` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_merma_exceso_clases1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`clases_idclases`)
        REFERENCES `clases` (`idclases`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Porque `idclases` no es única en su tabla. Debes declararla como única, sea definiéndola como llave primaria, sea otorgándole una restricción `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por brindarme su conocimiento y su tiempo