# Tengo una duda con esto

Tags: mysql

¿Puedo tener en una base de datos varias tablas con los mismos atributos?

por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `venta` (
     `cliente_idcliente` INT NOT NULL,
     `clases_idclases` INT NOT NULL,
     `fecha` DATE NOT NULL,
     `cant_bultos` INT(10) NOT NULL,
     `cantidad_um` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
     `valor` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
     `obsrvaciones` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`cliente_idcliente`,  `clases_idclases`),
     CONSTRAINT `fkcliente_clases_cliente`
      FOREIGN KEY (`cliente_idcliente`)
      REFERENCES `cliente` (`idcliente`),
      CONSTRAINT `fkcliente_cliente_clases`
      FOREIGN KEY (`clases_idclases`)
      REFERENCES `clases` (`idclases`)
      )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Esto ya lo preguntaste en dos ocasiones https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/563150/como-puedo-solucionar-esto ? .  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/563131/crear-una-base-datos . Recuerda realizar preguntas en base a [ask], saludos.

Comment: Ha realizado varias veces la misma pregunta

Comment: Yo no veo la misma pregunta. Tampoco entiendo muy bien el ejemplo. Si la pregunta es: ¿Puedo tener varias tablas con los mismos atributos? La respuesta es SI. ¿Tiene sentido tenerlas? Depende. Normalmente no. Lo más apropiado, parece tener un atributo adicional que diferencie los registros de esas tablas. Pero sobre todo, cuando realices una pregunta, intenta ser muy claro con lo que estás preguntando. Y establecer un escenario. Sino las preguntas que no son claras o están basadas en opiniones, terminan cerradas o sin respuestas. Revisa el enlace que te han puesto ya sobre Cómo preguntar.